# I cannot access class inside same namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, web-applications, namespaces

I am trying to access class inside same namespage but i cannot access instance of class.

```
namespace WebProj.Controller
{
    public class DataLayer
    {
        public string ConnString { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WebProj.Controller
{
    public class BusinessLayer
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using it in a method declaration;

```
namespace WebProj.Controller
{
    public class BusinessLayer
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            DataLayer d = new DataLayer();
            d.ConnString
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You need to put that code inside a method:

```
public class BusinessLayer
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        DataLayer dal = new DataLayer();
        dal.ConnString = ...;
    }
}
```